# Transfering file chosen text in Browse Dialog box to the Text Input field in Powershell

Tags: file, powershell

Trying for the first time a custom dialog box in Powershell v3. I wanted to add a browse button to the form. I have it so it shows the browse button but I cant seem to figure out the part where we take the file name from the OpenFileDialog  object and get it to appear in the objTextBox field. I've researched but cant seem to find any article that explains this part of the process.

```
$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objTextBox.Name = 'Text1' 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 



#File Browser Code.

    $FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
        InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
    }


$browse_button = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$browse_button.Text = "Choose...."
$browse_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,75) 
$browse_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,27) 
$browse_button.Add_Click({[void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($browse_button)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would approach it slightly differently. I'd make a function (which I just happen to keep on hand) that displays the Browse Files dialog, and outputs a string. Then for the Add_Click set the textbox's value = the function. Something like:

```
Function Get-FilePath{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [String]$Filter = "|*.*",
    [String]$InitialDirectory = "C:\")

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = $Filter
    [void]$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objTextBox.Name = 'Text1' 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox)
$browse_button = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$browse_button.Text = "Choose...."
$browse_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,75) 
$browse_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,27) 
$browse_button.Add_Click({$objTextBox.Text = Get-FilePath -InitialDirectory "$env:UserProfile\Desktop"})
$objForm.Controls.Add($browse_button) 
$browse_button.Text = "Choose...."
$browse_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,75) 
$browse_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,27) 
$browse_button.Add_Click({[void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($browse_button)
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. The only thing is the last five lines are duplicate.Sorry I cant vote you up I don't have a fifteen on rep.